Closed form formula
Let $m$ and $n$ are positive integers, then find the sum of the infinite series defined as $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k\Gamma(m+k) }{\Gamma(m)k!(k+m)^n}.$$ I was managed to the sum with $m=2$ and $3$ and whne $m=2$ the sum is  $\Gamma(n)(\eta(n)-\eta(n-1)).$

If $F_n(x):=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x)^k\Gamma(m+k) }{\Gamma(m)k!(k+m)^n}$, then consider $\frac{d}{dx}(F_n(x) x^{k+m})$, related to $F_{n-1}(x)$.  Of course $F_0(x)$ is easy.

Expression for $\frac{1}{(k+m)^n}$:
$$
\frac{1}{(k+m)^n} = \frac{1}{m^n} \left( \frac{(m)_k \times (m)_k \times \cdots \times (m)_k}{(m+1)_k \times (m+1)_k \times \cdots \times (m+1)_k} \right),
$$
where the products  $(m)_k$ and  $(m+1)_k$ are repeated $n$ times in the numerator and the denominator, respectively.
Series Representation in Terms of Hypergeometric Function:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(m)k^{n+1} , (-1)^k}{(m+1)k^n , k!} = \frac{\Gamma(n)}{m^n}{}{n+1}F{n}\left(m, m, \ldots, m; m+1, m+1, \ldots, m+1; -1\right).
$$
